# List disconnected devices via Xcode CLI

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xctest

Is there a way to list disconnected devices from Xcode via the Xcode command line tools? The closest I've found is this:

```
xcrun xctrace list devices
```

But, this only lists actively connected devices. `man xctrace` yields no arguments to retrieve more info.

Note that the `instruments` command is now deprecated and removed.

Is there a non-GUI-dependent way to access the disconnected devices? Like the ones shown here:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode devices window, with disconnected devices in the list]